# sbteclipse additional source folders

Tags: scala, sbt, sbteclipse

How do I configure an extra folder for sbteclipse to include? I have a default sbt directory layout with an additional it/scala folder. I want that folder to be included in the generated .project and .classpath files, but I don't know how to do that....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this for example by adding something like the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <++= baseDirectory { base =>
  Seq(
    base / "some/subdir/src"
  )
}
```

For details of the relation between `unmanaged-sources`, `unmanaged-source-directories` and `scala-source` you might want to check the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths.html). After exporting the eclipse project from sbt, you should find a corresponding entry in your `.classpath` file, like:

```
  <classpathentry output="target/scala-2.9.1/classes" path="some/subdir/src" kind="src"></classpathentry>
```

Answer (score 0):

there can be case in which you may just want to add a folder say **conf** to the eclipse classpath which contains configurations required at runtime. Below is the trick -

```
unmanagedJars in Compile ++= {
    val confBase = (baseDirectory.value ** "conf")
    confBase.classpath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add, e.g., the folder `src/folderXYZ`, then add to `build.sbt`:

```
Compile / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "src/folderXYZ"
```